# Prestashop - Where to look into webservice API

Tags: prestashop

I'm very new to Prestashop programming and I have a task regarding fixing current Prestashop webservice since we spot something wrong with it.

I'm not familiar to Prestashop programming so I have a question regarding where I can find the particular code of webservice for example for products resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to get access to the prestashop administration panel first. There under Tools ->  Webservice, you will see the list of preconfigured endpoints and accounts. That will be a great starting point to know what the current implementation is capable.
Also have a peek at the prestashop docs for information about usage http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

Update:
If you need the actual code that handles the request it is in yourshop.com/webservice/dispatcher.php

It invokes the class methods that are supposed to provide the web service actions.

Comment: thanks povilasp, but what I really want is digging in the code. I want to know which part of code that returns the REST call, because we found something wrong with the API and I want to know where it is to fix it :)

Comment: ah, I see, i'll expand the answer